# Ubuntu 12.04 & 13.10 won't boot from USB pen

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 13.10, live-usb

I tried with both 32bit versions, 12.04 & 13.10, but none of them will boot.
I create the usb drive with pendrivelinux, i pick the destro, iso, format and go.
As mentioned below, i also tried unitbootin and lili, but same result.

When machine turns on it doesn't matter if i use f12 or go through bios. When it tries to boot it shows one line of text for less than a sec, then goes on to a blinking _ in the top left corner and then nothing happens until i shut it down.

I'm using a packard bell dot se, aka netbook with win7.

Comment: Try using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I did, first i tried unetbootin, then i tried linuxpendrive twice. No difference.

Comment: Can you add the exact model of the netbook to the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever model dot_se-333nc

Comment: I guess that if any of those programs ain't working then this machine isn't linux compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting from usb second time,
with me every alternate boot attempt with LiveUSB is successful.

Try LiLi USB creator
http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Comment: I've tried booting 10 times now, no difference. Will try lili.

Comment: Tried lili, didn't work either, drive works fine, is detected fine by windows and bios, when selected it boots to flashing _ in the top left corner. After 3 min there's no change.

Answer (score -1):

Wipe the USB disk with the disk utility under accessories.
Then use unetbootin.

Comment: That doesn't exsist, neither in accessories, or accessories/system tools. But how is that different from right-click device and click format?